# Search event stopped firing in iOS 17.2 beta versions

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic5, ios17

`search` event is not fired in iOS 17.2 beta versions. This is working fine in iOS17.1 versions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/search_event

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" (search)="search($event)">
```

**Script**

```
search(event) {
    console.log('on search event:', event);
}
```